# Migration looks ok but is failing with an error

Tags: fluent, vapor

I have `Migrations` creating my models in a MySQL DB and this is working.

Now, I want to seed the DB with some demo data, so I created a `SeedDB` `Migration` for the sole purpose of this (of course, this migration is running after creating all model migrations).

```swift
struct SeedDB: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
                 Setup.createDemoData(database: database)
                 ...
    }
}
```

I created a `Setup` model for doing setup stuff. At this moment, it is only creating the demo data, but may be used in the future for other things.

```swift
final class Setup {
    static func createDemoData (database : Database){
        let _ = Address.createDemoData (database: database).map{ address in
        let _ = Site.createDemoData(address: address, database: database).map {site in
        let _ = Appointment.createDemoData (site: site, database: database)
        let _ = Company.createDemoData(site: site, database: database)
        let _ = ....
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have to nest some calls because a `Site` can not be made without having an `Address`. An `Appointment`, `Company` and others need to have a `Site` as parameter... (in those models that is defined using @Parent relations).

On the level on creating a `Site` from an address this works (as expected) perfect. However, if I want to create an `Appointment` (or `Company`) there is problem, even though the migration seems to be successful there is an error :

> Would you like to continue? y/n> y Migration successful Fatal error:
> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file
> NIO/CircularBuffer.swift, line 538

My models look like:

In each of my Models I have one of the following versions of these functions (depending on the needs) :

```swift
    static func createDemoData (database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<myModel> {
        
        let newMyModel = myModel(param1: "some stuff", param2: "demo info")
        return newMyModel.save(on: database).map{newMyModel}
    }
```

or

```swift
    static func createDemoData (site: Site database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<myModel> {
        
        let newMyModel = myModel(param1: "some stuff", param2: "demo info")
        return newMyModel.save(on: database).map{newMyModel}
    }
```

or similar...

FYI removing the .save(on: database) in the createDemoData  in Appointment or Company makes the error not happening (but also not saving the instance to the DB)

---

*Added model Appointment per request of  0xTim*

```swift
    static func createDemoData (site: Site, database: Database) -> [Appointment]{
        
        var appointment: Appointment
        var appointments : [Appointment] = []

        
        let today = Date()
        let day = TimeInterval(24.0 * 3600.0)
        
          
        //Planned appointments
        appointment = Appointment(siteID: site.id!, appointmentDate: (today+(3*day)), description: "Call James Bond")
        let _ = appointment.save(on: database)
        appointments.append(appointment)

        
        ....
```

As far as I know `site.id!` is not the culprit, since it is created in the `Setup` `Model` with the `createDemoData` for the appointment in its closure. (see code above).

---

*Added createDemoData for Site class per request of  0xTim*

```swift
    static func createDemoData (address : Address, database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Site> {
                    
            let site = Site(name: "mySite", addressID: address.id!)
            return site.save(on: database).map{site}
        }
```

Again, `address.id!` should not be the problem as `Site.createDemoData` is in the closure of the address creating (so it should exist).

Comment: I have seen this error when creating instances of models that have optional fields. Although the field is optional, it seems that vapor needs them to be initialised. Is it possible you have one of these lurking somewhere?

Comment: What does your create function for appointment or company look like and how are you using site in those functions?

Comment: @0xTim: added the appointment creation to the text

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you're not handling your futures. Every time you do

```swift
let _ = appointment.save(on: database)
```

Or similar you're telling the compiler to return immediately whether or not the save has returned or even succeeded. You need to handle the futures correctly with `map`/`flatMap`. It's the same with your migration

```swift
let _ = Address.createDemoData (database: database).map{ address in
  let _ = Site.createDemoData(address: address, database: database).map {site in
    let _ = Appointment.createDemoData (site: site, database: database)
    let _ = Company.createDemoData(site: site, database: database)
    let _ = ....
  }
}
```

There's no guarantee (and it's quite likely) that you'll attempt to create the `Appointment` before the `Address` has completed etc

Comment: That was my first idea too, but if you look into my code (second block of my post) you will see that the Appointment is created in the closure of Site, which is in the closure of Address (Site is created perfect)

Comment: What does the createDemoData function look like for Site?

Comment: added it to the original post

Comment: If you remove all the force unwraps and replace them with guard let's and add a message in, where does it fail?